# Date SQL in oracle throwing error - ORA-01858 Error message - ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected 01858

Tags: oracle

```sql
SELECT TO_DATE(pa.actual_exp_date, 'YYYYMMDD') - TO_DATE('20230531', 'YYYYMMDD')
         AS out_days
FROM   pre_agrees pa
       JOIN pass p ON pa.pre_id = p.pass_id
WHERE  pa.prepaid_status = 'A'
AND    to_char(pa.actual_exp_date, 'YYYYMMDD') >= '20230531'
AND    actual_exp_date IS NOT NULL
AND    to_char(p.effective_date, 'YYYYMMDD') <= '20230531';
```

Comment: Are `actual_exp_date` and `effective_date` `date` columns?  Or are they `varchar2`?  Or `number`?  Or something else?  It doesn't make sense to call `to_date` on a `date` since it is already a `date`.  It doesn't make sense to store dates as anything but `date`.

Comment: You're doing both `TO_DATE(pa.actual_exp_date ...)` and `to_char(pa.actual_exp_date ...)` so at least one of those is wrong, and relying on implicit conversion and your NLS settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never use `TO_DATE` on a value that is already a `DATE` data-type.

If `pre_agrees.actual_exp_date` and `pass.effective_date` are both `DATE` columns then:

```sql
SELECT TRUNC(pa.actual_exp_date) - DATE '2023-05-31' AS out_days
FROM   pre_agrees pa
       JOIN pass p ON pa.pre_id = p.pass_id
WHERE  pa.prepaid_status  =  'A'
AND    pa.actual_exp_date >= DATE '2023-05-31'
AND    p.effective_date   <  DATE '2023-05-31' + 1;
```

*Note: The `actual_exp_date IS NOT NULL` filter is unnecessary as `pa.actual_exp_date >= DATE '2023-05-31'` will only be true if the column is `NOT NULL`.*

---

If `pre_agrees.actual_exp_date` and `pass.effective_date` are both `VARCHAR2` columns then (apart from it being bad practice to store dates as strings):

```sql
SELECT TO_DATE(pa.actual_exp_date, 'YYYYMMDD') - DATE '2023-05-31' AS out_days
FROM   pre_agrees pa
       JOIN pass p ON pa.pre_id = p.pass_id
WHERE  pa.prepaid_status = 'A'
AND    pa.actual_exp_date >= '20230531'
AND    p.effective_date <= '20230531';
```